# How can I export a .obj file with texture?

Tags: export

I use add-on to import a model from mmd, and I added texture pictures by myself and exported it as a .obj file. But I cannot see the texture in Windows 3D viewer. I tried to save the project as a .blend file and opened it again, I can see the texture. How can I export a .obj file with texture?(I'm new in blender)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: The texture is a separate file. You export the obj (obj + mtl ) and you must save the texture at the same location. If the texture is packed you have to unpack it first.

Comment: Yes, I did it very carefully but the .obj file can't show the texture.

Comment: But the model was from MMD so the bones of the model are Japanese, is that a problem?